# Django - Combine Approval subclasses with different foreign keys into one class

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have two models in my Django project.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Forecast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

I want to build an Approval model in a standalone app that allows me to combine the following two approval subclasses:

```
class ProjectApproval(models.Model):
    approver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    approved_object = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class ForecastApproval(models.Model):
    approver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    approved_object = models.ForeignKey(Forecast)
```

into something more generic like:

```
class Approval(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    approved_object = [whatever I want ... a Project, a Forecast, a Checkbook, a Plan]
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, Django has generic relationships:)

Have a look on django documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

an example of implementation would be the following:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType  

class Approval(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: Wow, I went through an entire tutorial book and was never exposed to that. Thanks for pointing it out..